# How can I control one modifier on five different models

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I've made a part of an watch chain containing five different models, how can I easily control the array modifier on all of them as if they were a single object?
[image: Model]

Comment: The best way to go I think is to join all meshes into one single object, and then put your array modifier on this single object.

Comment: Add a control Empty into the scene and create a custom property for it.
Drive the modifiers with the property;)

Comment: @Polosson how will i go about doing that then?

Comment: @Rens Well, it depends if you absolutely want to keep separated objects, or if you don't mind having only one with multiple meshes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/index.html#drivers) you can use one value to control multiple settings.

In the watch (or the first strap piece), add a custom property called `StrapLength` then use that property to drive the array modifier value of the other pieces. Right click on the array count value and select `Add Driver`, then in the driver properties you set it to use a single property and select the object and set the path to `["StrapLength"]`. Repeat for each piece in the strap.

[image]

Then when you adjust the property, each array using the value in the driver will change at the same time.

[image]